# Magento 2 don't generate custom CSS file

Tags: magento2, layout, css

I got very strange issue with Magento 2 and custom css files. I'm trying to add custom css to the head

```
<head>
    <link src="js/bundle.js"/>
    <css src="css/main.css" />
</head>
```

After I flush cache, do deploy and than I see all css files in

> pub\static\frontend\Sleepz\md\en_US\css

except of *main.css*

I tried to deploy in developer/default mode, did Di compile, guess everything.
What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add the your custom css in your theme folder

> app/design/frontend/theme_name/package_name/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

In **default_head_blocks.xml** file

```
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
      <!--  Add local resources -->

        <css src="css/main.css" />

    <!--  The following two ways to add local JavaScript files are equal     --> 
       <link src="js/bundle.js"/>

   <!-- Add external resources ->
   <css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" src_type="url" />

 </head>
 </page>
```

Comment: well, will try in now. But does it really matter default_head_blocks.xml or default.xml?

Comment: it didn't help, same issue

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing my cutom module files , it working

Link your css file using xml in your theme/module

```
custom_module/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml or ( default.xml )
```

In head of your layout xml put relative path like below

```
<head>
        <css src="Custom_Module::css/hb_vertical_reviewrating.css"/>
</head>
```

Put your custom css files at this location

```
/view/frontend/web/css/hb_vertical_reviewrating.css
```

Comment: Nope, it's also not working `Refused to apply style from 'site.com/pub/static/frontend/Sleepz/md/en_US/Magento_Theme/css/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

Comment: please check .htaccess file in the pub/static

Comment: @Oleg Is your problem solved

Comment: sorry for the delay. Yes now it's solved. I just reinstalled Magento again and this time everything works like a charm. I have no clue what was wrong at first time

Comment: Did you checked the . htaccess file ?

Comment: yes, first time and second time, .htaccess was the same. It's very weird issue